# SSH Bind to port 22 failed

Tags: ssh

After I updated my Ubuntu to 20.10 I started having problems with SSH. Every time the service starts at boot or when I manually start it with `systemctl`, it errors saying that the ports are already in use (no matter which one I specify on `sshd_conf`). Although this suggests that there is already an instance of ssshd running it doesn't make sense because `systemctl status sshd` returns that the service has failed to start. If I do an `nmap` on the host in question the ports are indeed open and I haven't found another application that is using them. There also seems to be another computer in the same network that is using the same IP and this is conflicting with the server. How do I solve this? Could an instance of an ssh server running on this other computer interfere with the server?

**Update**
Output of `netstat -lnp | grep :22`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Output of `ss -panetl | grep :22`:

```
LISTEN 0      128          0.0.0.0:22         0.0.0.0:*    ino:38210 sk:1c <->                                                  
LISTEN 0      128             [::]:22            [::]:*    ino:38212 sk:22 v6only:1 <->
```

Comment: "There also seems to be another computer in the same network that is using the same IP and this is conflicting with the server. How do I solve this?" You could use tools like `tcpdump` or Wireshark to trace network traffic from this IP address and look at packets' MAC addresses. If you have a database of devices and their MAC addresses, you find the culprit immediately. If not, the first three bytes of a MAC address identify the vendor, which should help finding the device. MAC addresses can be spoofed, but the effort to trace and analyze packets is low and worth the while I think.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion! I ran a tcpdump and I was able to find which computer was using the IP from the dns name. I will contact IT about this.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely another service or instance bound to the port - which one is unclear. Please run `ss -panetl` and `systemctl status` to verify and show us the output as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the old `netstat` program to see what's actually listening on the port:

```
# netstat -lnp | grep :22

tcp     0    0 0.0.0.0:22    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    639/sshd: /usr/bin/ 
tcp6    0    0 :::22         :::*         LISTEN    639/sshd: /usr/bin/
```

For me it shows `sshd` is the one using them running as PID `639`.  You have to run it as the root user in order to see the names of the programs (it will run as a normal user but will only show the names of programs your user account is running, not the system processes).

The other machine with the same IP address won't affect listening ports on your local machine, but it may make it difficult to actually SSH into the machine as the packets destined for your computer may randomly get sent to the other one, causing the SSH connection to keep dropping out or fail to connect.

Comment: lsof -i :22 does also the job